# Retrieve Freebase topics info in bulk

Tags: api, freebase

I need to retrieve the informations (image, name, description) of some Freebase topic ids.

I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099416/retrieving-multiple-articles-images-via-the-new-freebase-api) that I can use google RPC but it doesn't work for me as it only returns the description.

I need to retrieve info of about 100 topics and I can't do 100 API calls.

Is there another way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you explain more about the application? Why can't you do 100 API calls? Are these topics related in any way?

Comment: I can't do 100 API calls because it would be too slow. The topics are more or less related to one other topic but I think it's not relevant for my issue. In a perfect world I'd use a google RPC call that works with this API topic call GET https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MQL, construct a query to return what you need per topic, and then pass all the topic IDs at once.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to pass multiple IDS in MQL.

Comment: It is possible. It looks like this: {"mid|=":["/m/05qtj","/m/04jpl","/m/02_286"]}

Answer (score 2):

You can look up multiple topics with one Search API call like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?
filter=(any mid:/m/05qtj mid:/m/04jpl mid:/m/02_286)&
output=(/common/topic/image description)
```

(Of course, you'll need to URL escape the parameters. I just wanted to show what the filter syntax looked like)

If you're querying 100 topics at a time, your request URL might be too large to send as an HTTP GET so you need to send it as a POST instead with the following header set:

```
X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET
```